# Tess4J on Ubuntu Linux, UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, tesseract, tess4j

I am getting a getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError using Tess4j in Tomcat+Ubuntu(Linux)

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPICreate': /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.3.0.2: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
```

Library is installed via apt-get install tesseract-ocr, Tess4j version is 2.0.0, everything seems to work on a MacOS/OracleJDK1.7(64bits), but not in Ubuntu/Linux/OracleJDK1.7(64bits)

Some stackoverflow-search gives clues about wrong versions or library not present, but the library is right there...

```
ls -al /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.3.0.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4219544 Feb 25  2012 /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.3.0.2
```

Someone with a solution or a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tess4J 2.0 is compatible with Tesseract 3.03RC. Since yours is 3.02, you'd need Tess4J 1.x version.

Answer (score 0):

this may be the version of tesseract is not compatible to ubuntu version

as to me my program runs in win10 and ubuntu 16  has no  error ,but when in ubuntu 12.04  this error occurs

maybe  I install tesseract by the command

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

but indeed in  ubuntu 12 after i install by the flow

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install gcc g++
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool checkinstall
```

**Install Leptonica from source. The latest version as of writing is 1.69.**

```
wget http://www.leptonica.org/source/leptonica-1.69.tar.gz  (if you can't,download leptonica-1.69.tar.gz from the internet)
tar -zxvf leptonica-1.69.tar.gz
cd leptonica-1.69
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
sudo ldconfig
```

**Then install Tesseract OCR from source.**

```
wget https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
(maybe you can download tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz from the internet and then upload to the server )
tar -zxvf tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz
cd tesseract-ocr
./autogen.sh
./configure
make (this may take a while)
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

after this i solve this problem